# Vertically centering content in an element with no height, but padding

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, vertical-alignment

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/dbwvx42s

**Description of Issue:** I'm using Bootstrap to make some columns within a section. The section has zero height (e.g. `height: 0`) but 56.25% bottom padding in order to maintain the aspect ratio (16:9) of the other content on the page.

The problem I'm running into is how to vertically center the content within this zero-height, padded element. I've attempted a flexbox solution to no avail. I've tried inline-blocking the content and using vertical-align, which was also a no-go. I'm running out of tricks!

Any help appreciated.

**Code:**

```
#section-1 {
    background-color: #0099cc;
    color: #fff;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

Comment: What kind of content is it?  Text? markup? Images? tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an absolutely positioned child element containing the content:

```css
#section-1 {
  
  position: relative;
  
  background-color: #0099cc;
  color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

#section-1 div.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="section-1">
  <div class="content">
    Content goes here  
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, `div.content` can be used as a normal sized div.